# Create shadow Plane once for an AR object instead of in every frame

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

first I created shadow Plane in `renderer(_:didAdd:for:)`, and it is called once when the object is created. It works well until you move the abject around and you will see the shadows plan will be end in some point after moving.
So I move the creating shadow plan function to `renderer(_:didUpdate:for:)`, and now it is creating the the shadow plan in every frame, and each time I makes sure that I removed the last one and add the new one. It works fine. But since I will take snapshot 25 times per sec from the ARView, I think creating shadows in every frame can be harm to the performance.  Is it possible to create shadows plan once and tie it to the object?

here are the function that I use for creating shadow plan

```
  private func addShadowPlan(node: SCNNode, planeAnchor: ARPlaneAnchor) {
    
    for chidNode in node.childNodes {
        if let index = shadowsPlaneHashes.firstIndex(where: {$0 == chidNode.hash}) {
            chidNode.removeFromParentNode()
            shadowsPlaneHashes.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
    
    let anchorX = planeAnchor.center.x
    let anchorY: Float = 0.0
    let anchorZ = planeAnchor.center.z
            
    let floor = SCNFloor()
    let floorNode = SCNNode(geometry: floor)
    floorNode.position = SCNVector3(anchorX, anchorY, anchorZ)
    shadowsPlaneHashes.append(floorNode.hash)
    
    floor.length = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z)
    floor.width = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x)
    floor.reflectivity = 0
    floor.materials = [shadowMaterialStandard()]
    node.addChildNode(floorNode)
}


func shadowMaterialStandard() -> SCNMaterial {
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
    material.writesToDepthBuffer = true
    material.readsFromDepthBuffer = true
    material.colorBufferWriteMask = []
    return material
}
```

Comment: If I unserstand you correctly, you try to make a Plane (Shadow Plane) that kind of follows some positioning? You could try to create your shadow plane one (as a global Variable) and then just set the new position on every frame. Or you could use SCNConstraints to constrain the object to another.

Comment: Thank you so much @ZAY, but if I have multiple objects in the screen, I can't use a global variable, correct?

Comment: You could use a global array. It depends. If you want one single objet you can reposition it as many times as you want. Otherwise you need to handle all those objects. I might not fully understand what is your goal at this point.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I will do that, thank you so much